# IntelliJ complains about nullchecks on attributes when they are marked @NotNull

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA complains about null checks (notifying me they are not needed), when attributes to methods are marked @Notnull but checked afterwards.

I was under the impression that the @NotNull check is only for static verification and will not result in actual checking, thus manual checking is needed to throw appropirate exception (IllegalArgument) at runtime.

Am I doing something wrong? How, if possible, can I turn this off?

[image]

edit: I'm using `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;`

Comment: I think you're confusing `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` (which is used by the Java Bean Validation framework to validate the argument for you before calling the method), with JSR305 `javax.annotation.Nonnull`, which is used to specify that a non null value may not be passed to a method.

Comment: What's the package name of the NotNull annotation?

Comment: @JBNizet It is `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;`

Comment: Then gurghet is probably right. But beware that IntelliJ can only analyze the code it knows about. If that is part of a public API, you'd better leave that precondition check there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion may stem from the fact that you are trying runtime to check for the nullity *and* statically doing the same thing.

Intellij is thelling you

> Hey, you are already checking statically for that variable to be not null. If you are then doing the same thing runtime, it means you don't trust my compiler abilities to check statically! Shame on you!

Comment: I don't think that's the case. How could IntelliJ check that no null value is ever passed to a *public* method?

Comment: ... And you are not trusting yourself either. Double shame.

Comment: I'm working on an API, the method is public. Someone might pass null to it.

Comment: @Pétur If you can't be sure, then they do you annotate it with `NotNull`?

Comment: @Tom To benefit from static code analysis during development.

Comment: Asserting that a value should be not null in your code but could be null in someone else’s code may be more harmful than helpful since it’s an architectural ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The `@NotNull` Annotation is, actually, an explicit contrast declaring the following:

```
a method should not return null
a variable (like fields, local variables, and parameters) cannot hold the null value
```

The `@NotNull` annotation objective is to inform you if a return of the null value is prohibited for the method or null is an illegal value for a variable.

For more detail you can check [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html)

In your case, if you are checking `edge != null` that means edge can be null at run time and thus should be declared with `@Nullable` annotation.

Answer (score -1):

`@NotNull` means that compiler will not allow you to pass null values as arguments, so there is no sense in checking it manually, that's what Idea tells you. Also when data is dynamic and is coming from some external source, then this annotation is mostly used in conjunction with some validation framework, like http://hibernate.org/validator/, so again there is no sense in checking it for nullity, because execution will never come to this point.